# What would be a neater way of writing this data?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I have a bunch of property data listed like this, but I am looking to write it much neater. What way would you recommend to write this neater? I have a lot more property data than these.

```
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *energyEnhancer;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *energyEnhancer1;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *energyEnhancer2;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *energyEnhancer3;
```

I have to have property because I am passing data between view controllers.

Comment: Why not have just one property, an array of strings?

Comment: I have to pass data between view controllers.So if this is possible with nsarray I will be more than happy to do it.

Comment: Yeah, I think thats the best way what NNL is saying.

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with what you have currently. It's easy to go into "refactor-overload" with some of this. Think carefully about what you need to do. If you are afraid it's not neat enough, don't go and change it just for the sake of neatness. An array is only a good idea if the `energyEnhancer` objects are interchangeable. If it doesn't matter how many energyEnhancers you have, an array is fine. If you need 4, and they're all supposed to be separate (What happens if you need energyEnhancer1 but there are only 3 in the array? Which one do you pick? objectAtIndex:0,1,2?

Comment: @JustinAmberson - True.  If this is the *only* place in your code where you have this pattern then there's nothing wrong with it and it's not worth the effort to change.  If you find yourself repeating the pattern again and again then you need to think about how to use other objects as properties.  (It's not at all hard -- you just do it.)

Comment: It's possible that an array is an OK solution for @JoeWimper, but until he understands why it IS or IS NOT a good solution, I'd advise against changing it. It looks like right now he's on some tutorials on using properties to access data. When he finally has the "A-HA!" moment and all the OOP paradigms start making more sense, then he can revisit this and refactor as necessary. I'd hate to encourage you to start using NSMutableArray without you understanding why it's a good choice, but doing it because it's "neater"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The short answer:**

[The iOS Developer Collections Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/).

---

**The Whole Story:**

I think it would be a good idea to take a broader look at some of the Foundation classes that deal with [collections](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/), such as [`NSArray`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html), [`NSSet`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html), [NSDictionary](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and if you're feeling particularly esoteric, [`CFBag`](http://nshipster.com/cfbag/).

Your question suggests that you could benefit from reading up on general Cocoa patterns. Indeed, you can pass just about anything from one object to another. An `NSArray` instance is certainly no different than several `NSString` instances.

For example, imagine we have an app called "PassingData" [(GitHub link)](https://github.com/MosheBerman/demo-passing-data). I'm going to define a class which has our data, in this case, several "energyEnhancer" strings.

```
@interface PDDataSource : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *engergyEnhancer;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *engergyEnhancer2;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *engergyEnhancer3;

@end
```

Then in our view controller, we may try to access the energy enhancers, like so:

```
- (void)logDataSourceWithStrings {

    NSLog(@"Energy enhancer 1: %@", self.dataSource.energyEnhancer);
    NSLog(@"Energy enhancer 2: %@", self.dataSource.energyEnhancer2);
    NSLog(@"Energy enhancer 3: %@", self.dataSource.energyEnhancer3);
}
```

Another way to do this is like so:

```
- (void)logDataSourceWithArray {

    for(NSInteger i = 0; i < self.dataSource.enhancers.count; i++) {
        NSLog(@"Enhancer %i: %@", i, self.dataSource.enhancers[i]);
      }
}
```

An added benefit to using an array is that you're no longer limited by the number of variables that you've declared at compile time. Your game or fitness app just got that much more robust.

This is only one way of accessing data that's in another object. Other strong contenders are delegate protocols, notifications, and callback blocks. Typically, if you're directly accessing data in another class, you're probably doing one of three things:

1. Compositing: Creating a class that contains several objects that exist to help the parent class.
2. Accessing a singleton. Singleton classes are universally accessible classes that can only be instantiated once. They're controversial, but there are appropriate use cases.
3. Storing temporary state in an object.

If you want to model more than one kind of data, consider nesting your values (be it arrays, strings, numbers, or whatever) in a dictionary. This isn't always the case, though. I wouldn't want all of my classes to have a single `NSDictionary` property. Use your best judgement.

Another good strategy when modeling is to use the plist editor in Xcode to mock an object. Then you can make a class (or classes) that match the plist, in code.

It's really worth your time to familiarize yourself with the conventions and [Cocoa Design Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321535022). Lotsa luck!

Answer (score 2):

Rather than use an NSArray as some of the answers have suggested, I think you would be better off passing a Dictionary. This is more robust than an array, as you can use the keys of the dictionary to make sure you are getting the right values rather than depending on the order in an array.

Comment: Agree, dict would be much better.

Comment: It depends. I wouldn't want to see all of my classes have a single dictionary property. I'd suggest modeling the class on paper, or in a plist editor, until it all makes sense.

Comment: Of course it depends. I wouldn't want to pass huge amounts of data from one VC to another. I'm just saying if that's what he's doing, a Dictionary of key-value pairs rather than an anonymous array of strings is less likely to break.

Answer (score 1):

You can write like this..

```
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *energyEnhancer,*energyEnhancer1,*energyEnhancer2,*energyEnhancer3;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *energyEnhancers;
```

would be better.

Comment: I have to have the property as NSStrings because Im using it to pass data between view controllers.

Comment: @JoeWimper why you think NSMutableArray cannot pass data between VCs?

Comment: @JoeWimper - What is special about view controllers?  An object is an object.